# Error on "npm install socket.io"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to update my socket.io version (current is 0.9.11), so I've edited the package.json file to:

```
{
  "name": "aaa",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.3",
    "hjs": "0.0.4",
    "cradle": "0.6.4",
    "socket.io": "0.9.14"
  },
  "subdomain": "aaa",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x"
  }
}
```

I'm getting that following weird error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:113:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:81:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\apps\sms - part 2\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

So I have three questions:

1. How did I manage to install socket.io before + run my node.js server successfully ?
2. How is Python related to this ? I don't have Python on my PC and I didn't know I should have.
3. How to solve this issue ?

**EDITED**
Just forgot to mention that socket.io module doesn't get update and stays on 0.9.11 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is required by [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) for compiling [native addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

An example of one is [`ws`](https://npmjs.org/package/ws), which [`socket.io-client`](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client) depends on:

```
cwd ...\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
```

And, the difference for why it installed before is likely within `ws`. The project had specified a [`"scripts": { "install": "..." }`](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/v0.4.19/package.json#L15) that would allow for [failing to compile](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/v0.4.19/install.js#L18-L24) when installing. Both of these seem to have since (v0.4.19, at least) [been removed](https://github.com/einaros/ws).

---

One available fix is to install `node-gyp`'s dependencies, including Python. This would probably be best as it allows you to keep up-to-date with bug fixes.

Another is to specify a lower version of `ws`, that's still [compatible with `socket.io-client`'s dependencies](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/0.9.11/package.json#L22), by adding it to your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.3",
    "hjs": "0.0.4",
    "cradle": "0.6.4",
    "socket.io": "0.9.14",
    "ws": "0.4.19"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. when you say "install node-gyp's dependencies", do you mean just typing "npm install node-gyp" ? (with/without adding it to my package.json file?).
and do you mean to install it on my app's directory ?

Comment: @ohadinho Both. `node-gyp` requires python and others (depending on your OS) to be used and it's required now to install the latest versions of `ws`, which affects whether you can install `socket.io`.

Comment: after adding that 'ws' line you've wrote, I'm able to successfully install socket.io on my app without any errors.
BUT for some reason, when I hit "node" and "require('socket.io').version" I still see that the version is 0.9.11 ! why is that ?

Comment: so how can I check the server version ? and upgrade the client one ?

Comment: @ohadinho Correction: They've changes their source quite a bit in prep for 1.0. The value of `version` is [hard-coded](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/socket.io.js#L18) and apparently just didn't get updated as they tagged updates 0.9.12 - 0/9/14. You can possibly get the server version with `require('socket.io/package').version`. But, the client is up-to-date if it's 0.9.11. The server just got a few more versions than the client.